# How do I truncate HTML strings to remove broken invalid HTML fragments?

Tags: java, html, client

In my Java webapp, I create summary text of long HTML text. In the process of truncation, the HTML fragments in the string often break, producing HTML string with invalid & broken fragments. Like this example HTML string:

```
Visit this link <img src="htt
```

Is there any Java library to deal with this better so that such broken fragments as above are avoided ?

Or could I let this be included in the HTML pages & somehow deal with this using client side code ?

Comment: Can you check if NekoHtml libraries help you out? http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Since browsers will usually be able to deal with almost any garbage you feed into it (if it ain't XHTML...), if the only thing that actually happens with the input (assuming it's valid HTML of any kind) is being sliced, then the only thing you have to worry about is to actually get rid of invalid opening tags; you won't be able to distinguish broken 'endings' of tags, since they, in themselves, ain't special in any way. I'd just take a slice I've generated and parse it from the end; if I encounter a stray '<', I'd get rid of everything after it. Likewise, I'd keep track of the last opened tag - if the next close after it wasn't closing that exact tag, it's likely the closing tag got out, so I'd insert it.

This would still generate a lot of garbage, but would at least fix some rudimentary problems.

A better way would be to manage a stack of opened/closed tags and generate/remove the needed/broken/unnecessary ones as they emerge. A stack is a proper solution since HTML tags **musn't** 'cross' [by the spec, AFAIR it's this way from HTML 4], i.e. <span><div></span></div> isn't valid.

A much better way would be to splice the document after first *parsing it as SGML/HTML/XML* (depends on the exact HTML doctype) - then you could just remove the nodes, without damaging the structure.

Note that you can't actually know if a tag is correct without providing an exact algorithm you use to generate this 'garbled' content.

Answer (score 0):

I used [`owasp-java-html-sanitizer`](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/) to fix those broken fragments to generate safe HTML markup from Java.

> ```
> PolicyFactory html_sanitize_policy = Sanitizers.LINKS.and(Sanitizers.IMAGES);
> String safeHTML = html_sanitize_policy.sanitize(htmlString);
> ```

This seemed to be easiest of all solutions I came across.